# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method show(FragmentManager, String) from the type DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

Hey Guys i'm having a few issues with I think importation. I'm getting the error message in the title under `MyDialog.show(manager, "MyDialog");`

Anybody know what it means? I'm thinking some issue with importing but i'm not to sure.

Rest of code:

```
package com.example.sub_assignment1_2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class FragmentB extends Fragment implements MyDialog.Communicator {

    public FragmentB() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public void showDialog(View v)

    {
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
            MyDialog myDialog=new MyDialog();
            MyDialog.show(manager, "MyDialog");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDialogMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    }

}
```

I'm also having an issue under `Toast.makeText(this, message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` The displayed error is: `Toast.makeText(this, message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` Which i'm also thinking is an import error?

If anybody could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In `MyDialog.show(manager, "MyDialog");`
should you not have myDialog.show - ie the instance not the class? Calling the method on the class name would be a static reference, which doesn't require an instance.

Comment: myDialog.show(... you just need to make the initial m lower case

Comment: If you're having issues with Toast.makeText... you may have to instantiate Toast (like Toast toast = new Toast(); and then issue the toast.makeText line (with lower case t).